# giving the wrong result when date format is changed

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL. I'm executing a query which returns the latest and old date in the table. Currently the result displayed is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, I want the result to be displayed in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Below is my query:

```
select min(daterange) as minDate,
       max(daterange) as maxDate 
from   (SELECT to_date(table1.daterange, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as daterange 
        FROM   table1, table2 
        where  table1.sid = table2.sid) tt;
```

Please advice. daterange column in table1 is of type character varying.I cannot use `::date` to convert to date type, because i need to use this query in my java hibernate code and the java code is not recognizing `::`.
I tried using to_char and to_date but the result displayed is wrong dates.Please find the demo [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=be71263bd7eff85c433786b18d7dc436)

```
select min(daterange) as min_cf, 
       max(daterange) as max_cf
from   (select to_char(to_date(table1.daterange, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') as daterange 
        from   table1, table2 
        where table1.sid = table2.sid) tt;
```

Comment: BTW, you can use `CAST(field AS DATE)` instead of casting operator `::date` to avoid issues with Hibernate/JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it on this way, formatting final result.

> ```
> select to_char(min(daterange), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as min_cf, 
>        to_char(max(daterange), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as max_cf
> from   (select to_date(table1.daterange, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as daterange 
>         from table1
>         inner join table2 
>         on table1.sid = table2.sid) tt;
> ```
>
> ```
> min_cf     | max_cf    
> :--------- | :---------
> 12/07/2013 | 01/07/2019
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=5ee1f3066b97198aa94028c0a141ea2a)*

Comment: I'm glad to help